# How to detect the end of LongListSelector?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, scroll, longlistselector

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone 8. I have a page containing a LongListSelector which load data from a webservice and display it into the list `MyList.ItemsSource = list;`

I want to load more data when the user scrolls to the end of the list or approches to it.

I prepared the method:

```
var list = await LoadDataAsync(); //This method loads data for the next few elements to be displayed
foreach (var element in list)
{
    MyList.ItemsSource.Add(element);
}
```

But i can't figure out which event handler is responsible for this.

Please help me and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

In link below you have very good and complete solution for that:

http://danielvaughan.org/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your rapid answer. But your solution uses ListBox and I want to use LongListSelector which is specific to Windows Phone 8.